# Problems with current_user (session_helper.rb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authentication, session-variables

I'm following [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#top) regarding signing in. I've skipped the sign up chapter for now so I'm hardcoding the users. I've followed it very careful (about four times now), but I'm still having problems with the session, and current_user in particular.

**session_helper:**

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

**session_controller:**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

**the user model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password
  has_secure_password

  before_save :create_remember_token

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :ticket

  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 24 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  private
    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

end
```

**example:**

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to "Create projekt", :controller => "projects", :action => "new" %>
<% end %>
```

When I'm running my application it says that I'm logged in (all the things that should only be seen for a logged in user is shown and vice versa). I've tried to clear the cookies, restarted the browser and even tried another browser but it is the same thing.

The thing is that if I (in sessions_helper.rb) change from:

```
def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

to...

```
def signed_in?
  current_user.nil?
end
```

..i.e removing the "!" the login/logut works as well as the correct links are shown. But that also means the I can't use current_user because it's actually "nil".

So the question is why is current_user nil? What is wrong with the code?

**Here's the db model for a user:**

```
first_name       | varchar(25)
last_name        | varchar(50)
email            | varchar(255)
created_at       | datetime
updated_at       | datetime
password_digest  | varchar(255)
password         | varchar(255)
remember_token   | varchar(255)
```

Comment: Your `current_user` method returns nil. You say "When I'm running my application being logged...", how are you sure you are logged? Because it seems you are not.

Comment: @ByScripts: You mean logged out? Well... I have cleared my cookies and everything and restarted the browser so I suppose I am. Is there an easy way to see that?

Comment: I also think where you have put `flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!` Should it not be flash[:error]=''Invalid email/password combination'`

Comment: @Djj: Actually. flash.now is the same as flash except that it disappears when you change page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was finally solved and that was done by deleting all the (test) users in the database and create new ones (with seed).

The users was created before the changes was applied to the app as well as the db model, and that probably caused the problem.